# How to get AVG from DATE (not datetime, timestamp) and return DATE (not datetime, timestamp)

Tags: mysql, date, average

I am writing the code in java which use DATE columns from mySQL database.

I would like to get average from DATE column but:

-avg(date_col) returns not date yyyy-mm-dd but some kind "weird" number,

I read a lot of stack topics "get average from date" but everyone uses timestamp or datetime (not date)... and all i tried were not working for me.

To sum up...
I have to get average from DATE column, which returns me "yyyy-mm-dd" because my program is parsing it in the following etap.

How can i get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the date to unixtime, take the average and convert back to datetime:

```
select cast(from_unixtime(avg(unix_timestamp(dt))) as date)
from data;
```

Unixtime is simply seconds elapsed from 1970-01-01, so it is an integer where you can calculate the average from.

Comment: yes, it's working but it returns timestamp, Is it any possibility to convert it to date type?

Comment: @restarcik Just cast the column to date. Code added.

Answer (score 0):

DATE_FORMAT with UNIX-Timestamp will do the trick

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt))) , '%Y-%m-%d')
FROM data;
```

Thsi convert time intp 2019-11-30 .

But there are  [more Format options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: This will convert the result column to a string. If you want to keep it as date (application level may handle the strings and dates differently), better use `CAST`

Comment: you are right it depends what you want, but  in most times you only want to Format the date in a certain manner, I personaly use more date_format that cast.